# How to use MySql Triggers on system date changes?

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can we trigger a mysql trigger when the system date is changed? Let's say
We have a mysql table and it has a dateTime column and at a specific time of each day we need to update that dateTime column according to a specific condition. So is it possible to achieve this task in mysql?

Comment: Why not create a view (based on that table) that contains `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as one of the columns? In that case the value of that column will "change" each time the system time changes (that is every nanosecond or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can we trigger a mysql trigger when the system date is changed?*

You cannot create this trigger. There are only table INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE triggers.
One more thing - as I know, the MySQL server should be restarted after system date changing.